# How to add native image with phonegap-build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am using cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser that requires some native images to work. The plugin page said that I need to copy the images to some directories.

Doing that, works correctly, but unfortunately, all the builds are done with Adobe Phonegap Build.

How can I add this native images when building with Phonegap Build?

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of [cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser). This is not a direct answer to your question, however after some considerations and digging into PhoneGap Build, I've decided to implement an [experimental feature](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser#experimental-properties) in version [0.2.10](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser) that will probably help your issue. The gist is to allow loading images from your `www` directory.

Comment: Thank you! For now I am using a plugin to copy the resources, but this would be a very appreciated feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE (1/19/2015):

This fix was suggested by github user: @shamank

`push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": {
        "senderID": "mySenderId",
        "icon": "myIcon", // will look for myIcon.png in res/drawable
        "iconColor": "#00AABB"
    }
});`

To get the icon in the res/drawable folder, you need to create the folder structure: locales/android/drawable at the root of your project. Then, stick your custom icon in this folder with the same name as you referenced in the PushNotification.init. The build engine will move the assets under /locales/android/drawable to the res/drawable directory of the built apk.

END UPDATE

While the description in the question specifies this issue impacting  a single plugin, cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser, which has now been updated to pull from the www directory, the question itself refers to a much larger problem with phonegap build. Not every plugin will be able to accomidate you in this way. In some cases it will be impossible as with push notification small icons.

You can read more about this problem here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/118

It basically says that Phonegap Build can't copy any resources and we're out of luck trying to make it do what we want. However, you can take advantage of the fact that plugins can specify their own resources. You can create your own plugin to copy resources where you want them to go.

I made a template plugin repo that you can fork and add your secondary icon. Or you can just use it as a guideline to copy any resources you want. It's not the best solution - Phonegap Build offering a way to bring in resources from your application directly would be preferable - but it works!

https://github.com/kentmw/secondary-icon

EDIT: you can follow the progress of the PGB enhancement request here: https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/472

Comment: Do you know if it's still possible on PGB to get the icon to `res/drawable`? I don't see any mention to it except in the issue you mentioned.

Comment: I haven't used PGB or done mobile development for a couple of years.  @Fernando, do you know?